# can't add HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, spring

I didn't think I'd ask about this, but I can't connect html and css, and everything works strangely in general. What to do?
When Spring application is working, my html page works when going to its address, but without CSS, when I run the html page separately, not on the server, the error "404 Not Found" is shown, when I run the page separately in VS Code, CSS works, and in the last application that has the same package structure as mine the current one also works as it should, but it differs only in the Spring version and may be some dependencies, maybe you will have ideas?

github:https://github.com/NikitaMozolevsky/SpringSecurityReturnUpdate

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/registration.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/registration.css">
    <title>Register page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="login">
    <div class="login-triangle"></div>

    <h2 class="login-header">Registration</h2>

    <form th:method="POST" th:action="@{/auth/registration}"
          th:object="${person}" class="login-container">

        <p>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" th:field="*{username}" id="username">
            <div style="color:red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('username')}" th:errors="*{username}">Username Error</div>
        </p>

        <p><input type="email" placeholder="Email"
                  th:field="*{email}" id="email">
        <div style="color:red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="*{email}">Email Error</div></p>

        <p><input type="password" placeholder="Password"
                  th:field="*{password}" id="password">
        <div style="color:red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}" th:errors="*{password}">Password Error</div></p>

        <p><input type="submit" value="Register"></p>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);

body {
    background: #456;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.login {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 16px auto;
    font-size: 16px;
}

/* Reset top and bottom margins from certain elements */
.login-header,
.login p {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

/* The triangle form is achieved by a CSS hack */
.login-triangle {
    width: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border: 12px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #28d;
}

.login-header {
    background: #28d;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
}

.login-container {
    background: #ebebeb;
    padding: 12px;
}

/* Every row inside .login-container is defined with p tags */
.login p {
    padding: 12px;
}

.login input {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 16px;
    outline: 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 0.95em;
}

.login input[type="email"],
.login input[type="password"] {
    background: #fff;
    border-color: #bbb;
    color: #555;
}

/* Text fields' focus effect */
.login input[type="email"]:focus,
.login input[type="password"]:focus {
    border-color: #888;
}

.login input[type="submit"] {
    background: #28d;
    border-color: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.login input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #17c;
}

/* Buttons' focus effect */
.login input[type="submit"]:focus {
    border-color: #05a;
}
```

POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringSecurityReturn</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringSecurityReturn</name>
    <description>SpringSecurityReturn</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

CONTROLLER

```
package com.example.springsecurityreturn.controller;

import com.example.springsecurityreturn.entity.Person;
import com.example.springsecurityreturn.services.PersonService;
import com.example.springsecurityreturn.util.PersonValidator;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {

    private final PersonValidator personValidator;
    private final PersonService personService;

    @Autowired
    public AuthController(PersonValidator personValidator, PersonService personService) {
        this.personValidator = personValidator;
        this.personService = personService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String loginPage(@ModelAttribute(name = "user") Person person) {
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/registration")
    public String registrationPage(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person) {

        return "registration";
    }

    @PostMapping("/registration")
    public String performRegistration(@ModelAttribute("person") @Valid Person person,
                                      //an error is placed here
                                      BindingResult bindingResult) {
        personValidator.validate(person, bindingResult);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }

        personService.register(person);

        return "redirect:/auth/login";
    }

}
```

SECURITY CONFIGURATION

```
package com.example.springsecurityreturn.config;

import com.example.springsecurityreturn.services.PersonDetailsService;
import lombok.Builder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@EnableWebSecurity //указывает на то, что конфигурационный класс SpringSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final PersonDetailsService personDetailsService;
    private final String[] allowedPages = new String[] {
            "/auth/login",
            "/error",
            "/auth/registration",
            "/css/**"
    };

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(PersonDetailsService personDetailsService) {
        this.personDetailsService = personDetailsService;
    }

    //настраивает логику аутентификации
    //даем понять SpringSecurity что для аутентификации используется
    //именно этот AuthProviderImpl
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(personDetailsService);//упрощение
    }

    //настройка формы для логина
    @Override //переопределяется из WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //конфигурация страницы входа, выхода, ошибки и т.д.
        //конфигурация авторизации (доступ по роли к страницам)
        //работает с http
        http
                .csrf().disable() //че-то с токеном
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                //страницы доступные всем
                .antMatchers(allowedPages).permitAll()
                //остальные запросы недоступны
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and() //and - объединитель разных настроек, настройка авторизации
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/auth/login") //метод захода в систему\
                //SpringSecurity ожидает что сюда придут логин и пароль
                //SpringSecurity сам обрабатывает данные
                .loginProcessingUrl("/process_login")
                //что происходит при успешной аутентификации
                //перенаправление на /hello, true - всегда
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/hello", true)
                //unsuccessful with key error (located in view (th) show message)
                .failureForwardUrl("/auth/login?error");

    }

    @Bean //возвращается используемый алгоритм шифрования
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

}
```

[POSTMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8BKG.png)

[PROJECT STRUCTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IM9Ab.png)

[CSS HTTP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw7mE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have included registration.css twice -- remove this line `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/registration.css">`, which is incorrect.

Also, allow access to /css folder for unautenhticated users.

```
 http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
```

Hope this helps;

Comment: No, I forgot to write, one link is for CSS to work when I run it separately from the application, the second is for CSS to work when I unpack the application, and yes, I tried to run with one link, the result is the same, and the last application worked correctly with two links

Comment: and I also tried to add "/css/**" to allowedPages, I added SecurityConfig to post

Comment: @Nikita, is the url you're seeing in the browser correct ? What response status are you getting (under the Network tab)?

Comment: yes, it's correct, I added postman's screenshot, I think I have to create new project because of this f****** error

Comment: @Nikita, I meant the url for registration.ccs , which should be http://localhost:8085/css/registration.css? Check the Network tab in Developer tools (F12 ), you will see the status code for the css file. You may also share the image of your project's resources folder structure.

Comment: I go to the localhost:8085/css/registration.css in postman and it shows 200 status and CSS code, I add picture of resources structure and HTTP, it shows 300 status for some reason

Comment: @Nikita, your browser is trying to retrieve the css from localhost:8085/auth/css/registration.css, rather than just  localhost:8085/css/registration.css. Try to use server-relative paths (e.g <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{~/css/registration.css}"> and see if that will resolve the issue.

Comment: it worked! I am very grateful, I wouldn't have guessed it myself

Comment: I also understood why the page could not be found when I opened it separately from the application, the path to the html file that was generated automatically was incorrect due to the fact that I copied this application from the old one